# Python dictionary array

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to ask about a particular problem, I have encountered lately.

I have list containing items e.g.

```
list1 = ['library','book','room','author','description','genre','publish_date','price','title']
```

and dictionary containing keys and values, keys are items from list1 and values are its childs,e.g.

```
dictionary1 = {'room': ['book'], 'title': [], 'price': [], 'author': [], 'library': [ 'room', 'book'], 'book': ['author', 'title', 'genre', 'price', 'publish_date', 'description'], 'publish_date': [], 'genre': [], 'description': []}
```

Basically what i want to do is to go through items in dictionary1 and if value of certain key is also key with values, i want to add values of the value to the key.

For example:

```
'library': ['room','book']
```

book contains author, title, genre, price, publishdate, description.

And I want to add all these items to library key, so it would look like:

```
'library': ['room','book','author', 'title', 'genre', 'price', 'publish_date', 'description'], 'publish_date': [], 'genre': [], 'description': []]
```

Comment: Your `dictionary1` example is invalid; it has *two* `book` keys.

Comment: It doesnt have two book keys, as far as i can see..
I tried 3 nested FORs, which would do the trick of merging items together, but i couldnt find out how to go through whole dictionary all over again.

Comment: I think you can either try to build a tree first and collapse that afterwards, or you can look into  creating a helper object that marks which keys you already expanded were expansion means you added the children of another key. Or you loop with a queue of to expand items that is either a fifo or stack.

Comment: is maintaining the order important? What about duplicates? What happens with library - since both room and library get book, does it get two entries per key or just a collapse of both?

Comment: there may be duplicates in values but not in keys ofc. and maintaining order is not important

Comment: Have you thought about using objects to store this information?  It seems like you're taking a lot of information and then just rearranging it so that you can access it through loops or something, which may be easier if you create a whole bunch of objects and have them aggregate each other.

Just a thought, I may be way wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your big issues are:
You don't want to duplicate the data
You don't want to eat the data as you iterate.

```
  import pprint

  def main():
      inlist = ['library','book','room','author','description','genre','publish_date','price','title']
      mydict = {'room': ['book'], 'title': [], 'price': [], 'author': [], 'library': [ 'room', 'book'], 'book': ['author', 'title', 'genre', 'price', 'publish_date', 'description'], 'publish_date': [], 'genre': [], 'description': []}

      for item in inlist:
          values = set(mydict.get(item, []))
          workingset = values.copy() # preserve the original set of items so iterating doesn't go nuts
          for potential_key in values:
              # we're going to cast into sets to add them, then recast into lists
              workingset.update(set(mydict.get(potential_key, [])))

          if values:
              mydict[item] = list(workingset)

      pprint.pprint(mydict)
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

Comment: Your code seems to work almost properly, thanks a lot, but i would like to ask one more thing, when i used your code(same list, and dict)i got:

 'room': ['book',
          'publish_date',
          'description',
          'title',
          'genre',
          'price',
          'author'],
and 'library': ['book', 'room'],

i would like to have those items that are in room also in library, because library points to room and room points to book, and book to.... is there any way? thx a lot :]

Comment: Solved problem, added while loop, THX a lot man! :)

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
dictionary = ...//your input
dictionaryOut={}

list=[]

for key, value in dictionary
    dictionaryOut[key] = copy(value)

    if length(value[0]):
        list=[value[0]]

    while not empty(list):
        list.append(dictionary(list[0]))
        dictionaryOut[key].append(dictionary(list.pop(0))
```

This should do it as long as we are talking python and appending to value will actually update the list in your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary comprehension:

```
{key: set(values + sum([dictionary1[value] for value in values], []))
       for key, values in dictionary1.iteritems()}
```